# EF doing prefilter table by property/type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am using EF 6, and using code first migrations.

I had a table `Requests` before and it only contains one type of requests, now I started adding different types of Requests in there, and always when querying it with LINQ, I have to do something like this:

```
_repository.Requests.Where(r => r.Type == Type.BestRequest &&......)
_repository.Requests.Where(r => r.Type == Type.AwesomeRequest &&......)
```

In my `DbContext`, I have this `DbSet`, that is returned always:

```
public DbSet<Request> Requests { get; set; }
```

Is there a way to prefilter the requests, by doing something like this::

```
_repository.BestRequests.Where(r => ......)
```

**But I would still like to have single table in database, named Requests.**

Comment: Are you using TPH inheritance that has Discriminator column in the database?

Comment: No, I am not using it.

Comment: You've already got a repository. Why don't you offer properties like `_repository.BestRequests`?

Comment: @YuliamChandra Type is just an enum.

Comment: @GertArnold I am not sure that I understand. What does the `BestRequests` return then? I only have the `Requests` table, and dont't have a database table called `BestRequests`

Comment: No, of course you haven't. The property would return the filtered table. You basically wrap the filter expression in the repo.

Comment: @GertArnold Can you post an example in answer, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created extra properties in my `IRepository` and implemented them in DbContext like this.

```
    IQueryable<Request> IRepository.BestRequests {
        get { return Requests.Where(r => r.Type == Type.BestRequest); }
    }


    IQueryable<Request> IRepository.AwesomeRequests {
        get { return Requests.Where(r => r.Type == Type.AwesomeRequest); }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you could check out this [link](http://www.agile-code.com/blog/entity-framework-code-first-applying-global-filters/)

I used it before and it did exactly what i wanted.. but the problem is i always had to "apply" the filter.